# Using interactivity from multiple layers produced in TileMill in a single map

Tags: tilemill, html, mapbox

I have a MapBox.js map with several layers [here](http://slocountyfire.org/CalMAPPER/) .  I would like to be able to use TileMill's teaser and full interactivity on a few of the layers, but I have only been able to accomplish this for a single layer.  How can I have interactivty for multiple layers in this map?  The code for the map is [here](https://github.com/SLUGIS/CalMAPPER/blob/gh-pages/index.html). I saw an example from [MapBox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/multilayer-utfgrid/) but I don't know exactly how to implement it into my HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have enabled interactivity on your map by the line:

```
map.gridControl.options.follow = true;
```

...but have not used any grid layers at all.

Include the following lines below all declarations:

```
var gridlayer1 = L.mapbox.gridLayer('slugis.ii9na2o6').addTo(map);
map.addControl(L.mapbox.gridControl(gridlayer1));
```

I had the same problem where my clicks wouldn't open the desired pop-ups and I solved this way.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for! The bounty is yours!